# Javascript add span to li

Tags: javascript, html

I want my code to instead of creating two texts with my newly created span, i want it to say"Some text x2" and then x3 and so on.

Heres my code

```
 <div>
      <li id="myLi">
         Some text  (This is where i want my other text to be instead)
      </li>

 </div>

    <td class="add" onmousedown="myFunction()">Add</td>
```

When i click the td, it adds to the li but when i click several times it just comes more text. I want it to say "Some text x2" instead.

```
   function myFunction() {
var proc = document.createElement("SPAN");
var t = document.createTextNode("Some new text.");
proc.appendChild(t);
document.getElementById("myLi").appendChild(proc);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with [`.innerHTML`?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) You're problem comes from the fact that you're adding text nodes every time it's called. Instead, you should replace the existing content.

Comment: Yes i have heard about .innerHTML, but i dont know how i would implement it :/

Comment: Read the examples on the page I linked to. It's not too difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike said, you can do this with an innerHTML.
If I understand, what you want is :

```js
var i =0;
function doStuff(){
   var proc = "<span> my text instead x"+i + "</span>" ;
   document.getElementById("myLi").innerHTML = proc;
  i++;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <li id="myLi">
      <p> something </p>
    </li>
<div>
  
<button onclick="doStuff()"> CLICK ME </button>
```

Comment: `i` is a dangerous variable to use as he might use it elsewhere on the page as well. Better to create a unique variable name such as `textAdded` or something. Also, On first click it says `my text instead x0` which doesn't make much sense; better to check if `textAdded > 0` and add the `x#` after that's true.

Comment: I know, the comment was more for Eivind's sake than yours.

Answer (score 1):

How about this piece?

```
var globalCounter = 1;
function myFunction(){
  var current = document.getElementById("myLi");
  current.innerHTML = "Some Text x"+globalCounter;
  globalCounter++;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/munukadama/edit?html,js,output

Note you will be using global counter. If you want to avoid global conflicts, either come up with unique variable name, or encapsulate within a class as a private variable (see below).

```
function MyClass(){
    var counter = 1;

    this.update = function(){
        var current = document.getElementById("myLi");
        current.innerHTML = "Some Text x"+counter;
        counter++;
    };
}

var myInstance = new MyClass();
```

And then button will become:

```
<button onClick="myInstance.update()">Click me for Class!</button>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question of how to count the times the button is pressed.

Comment: Oh missed that part.. Edited the answer to include that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery solution & a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/hn5u0xs7/) to test it out with:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li id="myLi">
       Some text  (This is where i want my other text to be instead)
    </li>
</ul>

<a href="#" class="add">Add</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function myFunction() {
  $('#myLi').html('<span>Some new text.</span>');
}

$('.add').on('click', myFunction);
```